# How can I fix ImportError: No module named numpy?

Tags: python, random, scipy, matplotlib, networkx

I am trying to run a python script which has the following statements:

```
import random as RD
import pylab as PL
import scipy as SP
import networkx as NX
```

Where can I download these packages?

I have installed these packages and I get the following error when I run my code

I am getting the following error when I run the code

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\hplabs\Desktop\Dushyant\networkdemo.py", line 7, in <module>
    import pylab as PL
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\pylab.py", line 1, in <module>
    from matplotlib.pylab import *
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 129, in <module>
    from rcsetup import defaultParams, validate_backend, validate_toolbar
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\rcsetup.py", line 19, in <module>
    from matplotlib.colors import is_color_like
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\colors.py", line 52, in <module>
    import numpy as np
ImportError: No module named numpy
```

Comment: A search engine could have answered this quicker and easier (except for `random` of course)

Comment: which version of python is compatible with all these packages?

Comment: you'also need the numpy library which is used by the others, i've added the link in my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a link to the non standard libraries.  random is part of the standard library.

[matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/)

[scipy](https://scipy.org/)

[networkX](https://web.archive.org/web/20121115182146/http://networkx.lanl.gov:80/)

[numpy](https://numpy.org/) (reuired by scipy)

Answer (score 2):

1. 'random' is shipped with the standard library
2. pylab and scipy are part of [SciPy](http://www.scipy.org/SciPy)
3. Networkx [is available here](http://networkx.lanl.gov/)

Answer (score 2):

[random](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) is a standard python library module, no need to install that.

pylab and scipy can be found on the [SciPy](https://web.archive.org/web/20130419025503/http://scipy.org:80/SciPy) site

networkx also has a [site](https://web.archive.org/web/20121115182146/http://networkx.lanl.gov:80/)

BTW: These are all easily found using [google.com](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl)

Answer (score 1):

When installing Scipy, you also need to install numpy which it depends on. See [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20221127092309/https://scipy.org/download/). You are getting the error because numpy is not installed on your system.